# How to measure cputime in tcl without package?

Tags: tcl

How can we measure cpu runtime taken by tcl script to execute certain task?
PN: Without Packages

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are interested in the CPU time used for a while process run (in which case *on POSIX-y systems* you can use `time tclsh yourscript.tcl`) you can't get that information without an extension package as Tcl doesn't expose the required system call. Or use it internally either.

If you *can* use a package, use the `times` command in TclX on POSIX, and the support for [performance counters in TWAPI](http://twapi.sourceforge.net/v4.1/pdh.html#performancecounters) on Windows.

Comment: ok...Thanks but i think times will give me how much amount of time is taken by that specific command, i guess...